# loop=1 is not workin youtube-iframe-api

Tags: html, api, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

Hi I have to use a YouTube video in my website which should loop but loop=1 is not working I hope I am doing it in a right way can anyone help me (thanks in advance)

```html
<html>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1wUgMEaUUrM?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;start=40&amp;loop=1"
    frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please specify you need how many times you want to loop or you want to autoplay or you don't want to show related video.You can customize your youtube video [visit here for more info](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo)
comment if you need more help!
Thanks!
here is your solution

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item"id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1wUgMEaUUrM?&autoplay=1&mute=1&loop=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white&iv_load_policy=3&playlist=1wUgMEaUUrM"
      frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edx_narendra/rxuoLb5f/1/)

Comment: the video should autoplay and loop infinite time (until the page is open)

Comment: Note:autplay is not working since April of 2018 because Google decided to give greater control of playback to users. You just need to add &mute=1 to your URL

I have updted my answer please check!!